# Generating array of arrays takes too long

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to produce an array of all possible arrays of the form

```
[x,y,z,(n-x-y-z),-20*x+0*y+-70*z+-20*(n-x-y-z)]
```

for a given `n`, where `x`, `y`,and `z` are integers.

It does this correctly, but `n=20` takes about 2.3 seconds, and `n=100` seems like it takes forever.

I know the length of this array of arrays increases factorially with `n`.

My understanding is that numpy might allow for the more efficient creation of such a list, but I'm new to Python. Any suggestions on how to do this task more efficiently?

```
def total_outcomes(n):
  return [[x,y,z,(n-x-y-z),-20*x+0*y+-70*z+-20*(n-x-y-z)] for x in range(0,n+1) for y in range(0,n-x+1) for z in range(0,n-x-y+1)]
```

Comment: Please fix your post markup and make the code more readable

Comment: It's a triple nested loop, so takes O(n³) time. Using NumPy isn't going to change that.

Comment: Can you add example that is reproducible? Please see the [mcve]

Comment: @zipa, replaced the coefficients with real numbers so that it should be reproducible now. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need all of the data at once, or can you work on it row by row / field by field as well?

Comment: @Arne, I need at least some of the data at once. In any event, I'm very happy with pmarcol's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate through such combinations of x, y and z, so that their sum is not greater than n. If that's the case, you could create all combinations of x, y and z's from 0 to n, then create a boolean mask telling whether their sum is not greater than n and extract the right combinations. Check, if this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np

def total_outcomes(n):
    x = np.arange(n+1)
    y = np.arange(n+1)
    z = np.arange(n+1)
    xyz_combinations = np.array(np.meshgrid(x, y, z)).T.reshape(-1,3)
    sums = np.sum(xyz_combinations, axis=1)
    mask = sums <= n
    xyz_combinations = xyz_combinations[mask]
    x = (xyz_combinations[:,0]).reshape(-1,1)
    y = (xyz_combinations[:,1]).reshape(-1,1)
    z = (xyz_combinations[:,2]).reshape(-1,1)
    c4 = (n-x-y-z).reshape(-1,1)
    #c5 = value_argmaxrcev_bias_scrutiny(n)*x+value_argmaxrcev_bias_noscrutiny(n)*y+value_argmaxrcev_nobias_scrutiny(n)*z+value_argmaxrcev_nobias_noscrutiny(n)*(c4)
    c5 = ((-20)*x+0*y+(-70)*z+(-20)*(c4)).reshape(-1,1)
    return np.hstack((x,y,z,c4,c5))
```

It runs pretty fast; in my case, computation for n=100 is done instantly. The computations time also grows pretty fast, though; for n=1000 it gets stuck for ~100 seconds. As was mentioned in the comment, you'll not get past the computational complexity of this task. Casting the problem to numpy actually just makes the computations go lower-level (since numpy is written in C and wrapped in python), and therefore are faster than looping in python.

That code, for n=5, generates:

```
array([[   0,    0,    0,    5, -100],
       [   0,    1,    0,    4,  -80],
       [   0,    2,    0,    3,  -60],
       [   0,    3,    0,    2,  -40],
       [   0,    4,    0,    1,  -20],
       [   0,    5,    0,    0,    0],
       [   1,    0,    0,    4, -100],
       [   1,    1,    0,    3,  -80],
       [   1,    2,    0,    2,  -60],
       [   1,    3,    0,    1,  -40],
       [   1,    4,    0,    0,  -20],
       [   2,    0,    0,    3, -100],
       [   2,    1,    0,    2,  -80],
       [   2,    2,    0,    1,  -60],
       [   2,    3,    0,    0,  -40],
       [   3,    0,    0,    2, -100],
       [   3,    1,    0,    1,  -80],
       [   3,    2,    0,    0,  -60],
       [   4,    0,    0,    1, -100],
       [   4,    1,    0,    0,  -80],
       [   5,    0,    0,    0, -100],
       [   0,    0,    1,    4, -150],
       [   0,    1,    1,    3, -130],
       [   0,    2,    1,    2, -110],
       [   0,    3,    1,    1,  -90],
       [   0,    4,    1,    0,  -70],
       [   1,    0,    1,    3, -150],
       [   1,    1,    1,    2, -130],
       [   1,    2,    1,    1, -110],
       [   1,    3,    1,    0,  -90],
       [   2,    0,    1,    2, -150],
       [   2,    1,    1,    1, -130],
       [   2,    2,    1,    0, -110],
       [   3,    0,    1,    1, -150],
       [   3,    1,    1,    0, -130],
       [   4,    0,    1,    0, -150],
       [   0,    0,    2,    3, -200],
       [   0,    1,    2,    2, -180],
       [   0,    2,    2,    1, -160],
       [   0,    3,    2,    0, -140],
       [   1,    0,    2,    2, -200],
       [   1,    1,    2,    1, -180],
       [   1,    2,    2,    0, -160],
       [   2,    0,    2,    1, -200],
       [   2,    1,    2,    0, -180],
       [   3,    0,    2,    0, -200],
       [   0,    0,    3,    2, -250],
       [   0,    1,    3,    1, -230],
       [   0,    2,    3,    0, -210],
       [   1,    0,    3,    1, -250],
       [   1,    1,    3,    0, -230],
       [   2,    0,    3,    0, -250],
       [   0,    0,    4,    1, -300],
       [   0,    1,    4,    0, -280],
       [   1,    0,    4,    0, -300],
       [   0,    0,    5,    0, -350]])
```